# Runtime behavior with "C++ most vexing parse"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction, g++

While trying to answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039657/strange-error-in-using-templateclass-inputiterator-string-inputiterator-begin) question I found without `()` (which invokes "C++ most vexing parse") the output of g++ is `1` (Can be seen here: http://ideone.com/GPBHy), where as visual studio gives a linker error. I couldn't understand how the output can `1`, any clues?

Comment: Btw, Did you understand why msvc gives a linking error & not similar behavior?

Comment: @Als: From my understanding it tries to call the "function" `str` with the given parameters, since it can not find the method linker gives the error. But yeas I don't know why g++ doesn't give the same error..

Comment: @Als: my best guess would be that MSVC attemps to resolve the address of the declared function so that value can be converted to `bool`.

Comment: @Asha: It's not calling the function, but rather just resolving the function's address.  G++ is just converting the function address to `true` at compile-time while MSVC attemps to resolve the function address at compile-time and then convert to `bool` at run-time.

Comment: @AndréCaron: That seems to be the case, what surprises me is why this difference in handling? It's not a corner use case, a petty common one IMO.

Comment: If you cast `str` like `cout<<(void*)str<<endl;` g++ will give you an undefined reference ([example](http://ideone.com/9poe0)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the answers to the question already explain, due to the "Most Vexing Parse" the statement instead of defining an object named `str` with the two `istream_iterators` to specify its initializers, is parsed as a declaration of a function named `str` that returns a `string`.

So a simple version of the program resolves to, **[this online sample](http://ideone.com/lAAjF)**:

```
#include<iostream>  

void doSomething()
{
} 
void (*ptr)()=&doSomething;

int main()
{

    std::cout << ptr << "\n"; 
    std::cout << doSomething;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
1
```

Note that there is no overloaded `operator <<` that takes an `std::ostream` and a function pointer as arguments, this is because there can be any number of user defined function types and ofcourse a standard overloaded api cannot account for them all.

Given that the compiler tries to find the best match among the existing overloads which happens to be `bool` (a function pointer is implicitly convertible to `bool`<sup>[#1]</sup>).
In particular,

```
basic_ostream& operator<< (bool& val );
```

Since the function pointer points to something and not `null`, the value is printed as `1`.

---

<sup>[#1]</sup>**C++03 4.12 Boolean conversions**

> 1 An rvalue of arithmetic, enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to an rvalue of type bool.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you feel something is wrong care to add a comment or your own answer. For the record there is nothing wrong in this answer.